# if else statement (it only works with a number)

Tags: assembly

I can put a number in mov ax (example: mov ax, 2), but if I put a variable it doesn't work (example: mov ax, forma)

I'm new in assembly.

This is the code:

```
    ;if eles 
    mov ax, 2 ;forma
    cmp ax , 2
    jge l8

    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1
    mov cx, 2
    mov dx, pergunta3
    int 21h
    jmp l5


    l8:

    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1
    mov cx, 3
    mov dx, pergunta2
    int 21h
    jmp l5

    l5:
    ;terminar
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h
```

Comment: There are no "variables" in assembly. At best you have named memory locations.

Comment: Please specify which assembler you're using, as their syntaxes differ, and also what _"it doesn't work"_ means.

Comment: Declare forma in data segment: "forma dw 999". Now you can use it: "mov ax, forma".

Comment: Looks like Nasm syntax to me. Try `mov ax, [forma]`. Without the square brackets, you've got the address like `mov ax, offset forma` in Masm/Tasm.

Comment: im using fasm)
and the user put a value in forma and if (forma>2) the programe do the (l8:)

Comment: what variable you want? runtime (`forma db 2`) or preprocessor (forma = 2)? First case you use `mov ax, [forma]`; Second - `mov ax, forma`

Answer (score 0):

```
;if eles 
mov ax, 2 ;forma
cmp ax , 2
jge l8
```

FASM uses square brackets **[ ]** to access memory like your variable **forma**. So code it like this

```
mov ax,[forma]
cmp ax,2
jg l8
```

A shorter way to code it is

```
cmp word [forma],2
jg l8
```

Please note your comment says **(forma>2)** and thus `jge l8` should be changed into `jg l8`!